Why is the hFE value of a transistor not constant under the same conditions, but instead expressed as a range?
For the transistor in this datasheet, at 25 degrees Celsius, with VCE at 10 V and a collector current of 150 mA, a quite large range of 100 to 300 is specified for the transistor's gain.

Datasheet
However, what confuses me is why there can be a threefold difference in hFE values for the same transistor circuit under the same conditions. To clarify, my question is: What is the reasoning behind providing a range for the beta value in a transistor circuit that is set up under the same conditions?

The Hfe varies from part to part (same type) so much the manufacturers rather pick wide tolerances.

Making transistors is not easy. There are lots of parameters to adjust and control. hFE for a transistor depends on the emitter and base diffusions and the relative differences (micrometers) between them -- this is affected by the temperature and time the impurities were diffused for (say 700 °C for 300 s plus temperature ramp-up and -down times) - imagine controlling that with 1 % accuracy!
Good circuit design should not depend on a precise value of hFE -- usually just knowing a minimum should be sufficient; occasionally knowing the maximum can be important if AC loop stability is being analyzed. Therefore manufacturers can simplify processing and keep yields high by specifying a wide, 'safe' range for these parameters.
Notice that the critical ones (breakdown voltages, leakage currents are specified as min. or max. -- as that is sufficient for robust design.

Good, concise advice.


What is the reasoning behind providing a range for the beta value in a transistor

It is a kind of summary for this plot, in the same datasheet:


threefold difference in hFE values for the same transistor circuit under the same conditions

Not actually the same conditions. hFE varies a lot and the project should not be dependent on a precise value.
When a manufacturer presents tables with maximum and minimum values, these are the worst case parameters to be considered for the project (even considering process variations). Notice that this specific datasheet doesn't show typical values at the tables, which is consistent with what is normally useful for discrete BJT designs.
It is interesting though to show a typical plot so the variations with several parameters are better presented than in a worst case table. Also worth noting that anything above 65mA @ 10V is above the power rating of the component and the 3 last parameters consider a pulsed test (Note 1).

In this graph, looking at the curve where the collector current is 150mA, the temperature is 25 degrees Celsius and the collector emitter is 10V, the y-axis is constant and intersects at a single point, at about 250. However, the table states that this value could range between 100 and 300. First of all, this graph does not completely match the data in the table.  I’m also curious about this: hypothetically speaking, if I set the temperature, collector-emitter voltage, and collector current values the same for just one transistor circuit, does the hFE value change each time?

@pwr It varies from part to part, so if you take one P2N2222A out and replace it with another P2N2222A (especially if it's one from a different lot), even with every other condition exactly the same, you'll measure different values.

The variations shown in the plot are additional to the hFE variations from part-to-part at a fixed Ic and temperature. Care is required in extrapolating from one guaranteed range at a single operating point to some general operating point, especially around the RHS  of the plot where hFE starts to drop precipitously with current. Where (and by how much) that drop occurs will vary from part-to-part too.

"... why there can be a threefold difference in hFE values for the same transistor circuit under the same conditions".
It is a manufacturing variation in transistor characteristics. And you are correct, the variation is under identical conditions of Ic and Tj (the datasheet says Ta but there will be a note that it is measured using small duty-cycle pulses so Tj ~= Ta). So it is only a variation in the parts. Any variations due to different conditions- such as Ic or Tj can be estimated from the typical curves but they are not guaranteed (so some safety margin is required). Of course those variations are additional to the hFE variation under the fixed test conditions.
With something simple such as a switch you can accomodate the variation by providing a minimum base current (you'll note that your transistor has no maximum hFE at Ic other than 150mA, only a minimum). However for some analog circuits, accomodating such a wide range in hFE can be more expensive and power hungry than purchasing transistors with a more controlled hFE. However the manufacturing tolerance of 3:1 is about what is feasible, and more like 10:1 would ensure maximum yield, so how is it done?
Take the once-ubiquitous Toshiba 2SC1815:

You'll see the specification primarily aimed for those using the transistor as a simple switch- a minimum hFE is specified at a relatively high current.
Then there is another specification for more analog-y applications at an Ic of 2mA. You can purchase transistors with the given range of hFE values by specifying the suffix. I used a lot of 2SC1815Y parts, which have an hFE range of only 2:1 and minimum price. The GR suffix had a price premium and a higher hFE but still the same 2:1 range. Overall though the range was 10:1 over all types (70 to 700).
Colloquially, we refer to these as 'beta-binned' after \$\beta\$ and the bin they drop the transistors into after testing. Since the ranges overlap a bit if they aim for hFE = 220 or so they can make a pile that can be sold as either Y or GR, and a couple additional piles that have to be sold as one or the other.
Designers of bipolar integrated circuits have similar variations to deal with, but a major advantage in that transistors on the same die will be very closely matched to each other, especially if the design is tweaked a bit and the transistors are close together on the die. If the transistors are arranged carefully with regard to heat sources on the die they'll also be very close to the same temperature. That allows circuits such as current mirrors without emitter degeneration to work very well.
